# Textarea first line bold

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea in which I want the first line to be bold (and bigger font) as the first line contains the title. I tried the :first-line pseudo class, this works in IE, but fails in Firefox. Also in IE, enters doesn't work anymore, so I can't break the line.

Is this even possible? And if so, how?

regards,
Henk

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate it might not be intended to be styled, but it is possible (tested in Chrome).

```
<style>.h-textarea:first-line { font-weight: bold; }</style>
...
<textarea></textarea>
```

Gives a bold first line.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Textarea is not intended for displaying formatted text.

If you need this functionality then you can use a **WYSIWYG editor**.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of that, but since I only needed the first line to be bold and/or bigger, I wanted to know if there was a workaround for it :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the first line of the textarea to be bold after the user has finished entering all data?

You could handle that by having a js or server script grab the first line and put that in a separate variable, so it outputs it in a different markup (an h3, perhaps).

Or, if you want the user's title to just standout from the rest, why not have an input for the title and then a textarea for the body, like:

```
<form>
<p>
<label for="usertitle">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="usertitle" id="usertitle" />
</p>
<p>Body</p>
<p>
<textarea></textarea>
</p>
</form>
```

This way, the user gets that sense of importance you want. You could even add some javascript that changes the input to an h3 after they start tying in the textarea.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this, having the title and the rest of the text seperate.